# What are the input and the output of the Transformer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, transformer-model

I have questions about google implementation of the Transformer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/transformer).

- In `train_step(input, tar)` function: the `inp` dimension is a 256*40 tensor and the transformer returns a 256*39*8089 tensor. Is each row in `inp` a sentence?  I expected Transformer to take a batch of sentences (a batch_size of 2D matrix in which each row is a word) and calculate attention weights and outputs at once and then pass them to decoder (see [here](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/). ). However, I cannot see that being implemented in the code.
- In `train_step(input, tar)` function: the "predictions" is a 256*39*8089 tensor. Is it [batch size, max number of words in a sentence, target vocab size]? How does loss_function calculate loss while this format is different from ```tar_real`` which is [256 * 39]?
- In `def evaluate(inp_sentence)`: Why in each iteration it sends the Transformer the entire encoder input? What I expect is that the encoder calculates attention weights and output once and then inside the for loop we send the output of the attentions and the predictions so far.

Thank you